# Unable to configure maven ProGuard plugin

Tags: proguard, maven-plugin

I'm trying to use proguard plugin for reducing and optimizing my jar. However, I am facing difficulties in using this plugin. Below is my project pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.hps</groupId>
  <artifactId>geomesafrontend</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>geomesafrontend</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
      <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.locationtech.geomesa</groupId>
      <artifactId>geomesa-accumulo-datastore_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.accumulo</groupId>
      <artifactId>accumulo-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <!-- <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar> -->
              <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
              <transformers>
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.14</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.sf.proguard</groupId>
                    <artifactId>proguard-base</artifactId>
                    <version>5.3.3</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals><goal>proguard</goal></goals>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- <proguardVersion>4.10</proguardVersion> -->
                <options>
                    <option>-keep public class com.hps.EventServer{public static void main(java.lang.String[]);}</option>
                    <option>-keep public class com.hps.AvroCodec{*;}</option>
                </options>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>locationtech-releases</id>
      <url>https://repo.locationtech.org/content/groups/releases</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>osgeo</id>
      <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

when I run the command: `mvn package`, I am getting lots of warnings like regarding the duplicate definition of library classes and can't find referenced class java.lang.Class. At the end, the build fails. 
I am new to maven, any documentation which will help newbies in understand how to configure it correctly will also be helpful.